# How to navigate to anchor tag with tab key if it doesn't have an href?

Tags: html, angular

I've got a navbar in our app that has a bunch of buttons that are links to other pages, and then a conditional logoff/logon button. That button is an `<a>`, but it just has `(click)` and no `href` or `routerLink`.  As such, I can't tab to it.  I added `routerLink=""` which is working, but seems really hacky.  Is there a class or something I can add to make it "tabbable"?

Here's the navbar as it was before I added that `routerLink=""`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard </a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/studentaccount" routerLinkActive="active">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="" (click)="logout()">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding tabindex="0" should solve it. E.g.

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" tabindex="0">
```